# Basic CSS styling issue

Tags: html, css

I'm making a new website and in my sidebar I'm trying to add this section below but I'm struggling to get the about text to be to the right of the image. I've tried floating the text left but it didn't really work. The only CSS I've got so far is that the sidebar is 300px wide.

```
<div id="sidebarabout">
    <h3>About Elliott Davidson</h3>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus luctus odio, sed sagittis dolor volutpat ut. Pellentesque efficitur orci at nunc fermentum, nec feugiat erat gravida. <a href="about.html">Continue reading</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to float img not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css and check out

```
img{float:left;padding:0 15px 0 0}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/s4pb17tr/

Comment: I'd move away from suggesting `float`s, they *always* cause layout issues.. besides - you're floating *all* his images!?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar the programer have to mention a specif class to achive it.

Comment: Where exactly? I don't see this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus luctus odio, sed sagittis dolor volutpat ut. Pellentesque efficitur orci at nunc fermentum, nec feugiat erat gravida. <a href="about.html">Continue reading</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{float:left;margin:0 15px 0 0}
```

Padding will squeeze your image little.
You can use margin instead of padding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the img and p to be either `inline` or `inline-block` on their CSS styles.

And also - depending how you want your text to "float" it may need a width:

https://jsfiddle.net/xoL510og/ << Example

```
<div id="sidebarabout">
    <h3>About Elliott Davidson</h3>
    <img style='display:inline-block;' src="http://placehold.it/100x100"><p style='display:inline-block; width:400px;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus luctus odio, sed sagittis dolor volutpat ut. Pellentesque efficitur orci at nunc fermentum, nec feugiat erat gravida. <a href="about.html">Continue reading</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display: table;`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.item-inner{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;    
    padding: 20px;
}
.item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.item-text{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
   
    <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus luctus odio, sed sagittis dolor volutpat ut. Pellentesque efficitur orci at nunc fermentum, nec feugiat erat gravida. <a href="about.html">Continue reading</a></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining the img markup, make sure that it **only affects** the sidebarabout div. So define the div before img. Example:

```
#sidebarabout img{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

In case u declared a width in ur paragraph element, for example 200px, make sure to reduce this to 185px, since we're using a 15px padding. Otherwise it will mess up ur webpage because the div will become 315px width.

I noticed someone suggested using a margin. Don't use a margin, this will only push the image 15px to the left out of the div.

Also i'm missing a *width, height* and *alt*. Make sure to define ur **img** element the right way, otherwise it will **not pass** the W3C validator. Use the following:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" alt="Description">
```